# Can Antagonize force someone to run through threatened areas?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, opportunity-attack

The question is quite simple, Antagonize says:

> The creature flies into a rage. On its next turn, the target must attempt to make a melee attack against you, make a ranged attack against you, target you with a spell, or include you in the area of a spell. **The effect ends if the creature is prevented from attacking you or attempting to do so would harm it** (for example, if you are on the other side of a chasm or a wall of fire). If it cannot attack you on its turn, you may make the check again as an immediate action to extend the effect for 1 round (but cannot extend it thereafter). The effect ends as soon as the creature attacks you. Once you have targeted a creature with this ability, you cannot target it again for 1 day.

In particular see the bold section.

What I'm unsure about is situations like Attacks of Opportunity, they are not guaranteed to harm it - but there is a risk they will. Can Antagonize make a target run through friendly threatened areas and risk taking the AoO in order to get to you?

Answer (score 5):

There is no answer under RAW, nor any developer statement on the matter (As far as I have been able to find). The following answer is based on how I would run it:

There is a difference between potential harm and definite harm. I would rule this along the following lines:

- If they are forced to move through a square or effect that would cause automatic damage, then the feat fails. I would extend this to requiring a roll to avoid damage since the damage happens by default (you take the consequences if you don't make a roll)
- If they are forced to move through a square where there is a chance of damage, but that damage is not assumed by default, then the feat does would not automatically fail. Attacks require a roll to hit, damage is not assumed as the default outcome.

Answer (score 0):

**To reword Mourdos's answer, that would depend on the situation that you use it.**

For example, if you antagonize a bull that was across a room or an open field, that guy would probably charge right at you. However, a bandit would probably be wiser than that. They would most likely try to find a way **around** your allies or a way that would cause them the least harm (such as if there was a big enough gap between your allies to slip through, or a reachable tree they could land on top of you from). Furthermore, there are a good number of feats that would allow them to pass through threatened areas without harm, such as the ever useful [Charge Through](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/charge-through-combat).

So in other words **Yes, it can take risks to move through threatened areas to attack you, but it can take *other* risks to get the same result!**